# Numpy group scalars into arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array `U` with shape `(20, 50)`: 20 spatial points, in a space of 50 dimensions.

How can I transform it into a `(20, 1, 50)` array, i.e. 20 rows, 1 column, and each element is a 50 dimension point? Kind of *encapsulating* each row as a numpy array.

**Context**

The point is that I want to expand the array along the columns (actually, replicating the same array along the columns X times) using `numpy.concatenate`. But if I would do it straight away I would not get the result I want.

E.g., if I would expand it once along the columns, I would get an array with shape `(20, 100)`. But what I would like is to access each element as a 50-dimensional point, so when I expand it I would expect to have a new `U'` with shape `(20, 2, 50)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `U[:, None, :]` to add a new dimension to the array.

Comment: Such an elegant solution, but I can't really grasp why it works... Would you mind elaborating a bit, please?

Comment: @houcros: See the description in [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing).  Basically None (or `np.newaxis`) tells numpy to insert a new dimension at that position.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `reshape`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((20, 50))
print a.shape # (20, 50)
b = a.reshape((20, 1, 50))
print b.shape # (20, 1, 50)
```